# How do you implement exec_module for a custom Python module loader?

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I want to implement a custom Python module loader, as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). The process seems pretty straightforward, except I don't how to eventually delegate to the default loading process, which I think I want do when I implement `exec_module`.

So for example, I can put this 'Finder' on the `sys.meta_path` and it gets called when I `import` a module.

```py
import sys
import importlib.machinery
import types

class Finder:    
    def find_spec(name, path, target):
        print(f"find_spec: {name}, path={path}, target={target}")
        if not name.startswith('my_prefix.'):
            return None
        return importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(name, Finder, is_package=True)
            
    def create_module(spec):
        print(f"create_module, spec = {spec}")
        mod = types.ModuleType(spec.name)
        return mod

    def exec_module(mod):
        print(f"exec_module, mod = {mod}")
        # How to use a file here, to define the module?
        mod.test = 123

sys.meta_path.append(Finder)
import my_prefix.foo
```

Those three functions get called as expected. Now let's say I want to load a certain file to define most of the `my_prefix.foo` module. How do I do that inside `exec_module`? Do I manually read the code from the file and call the builtin [exec function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec)? Or is there a better way to do that when defining modules?

Answer (score 0):

There's no general rule what methods `exec_module`, `create_module` should do. But according to documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html and file `importlib.abc.pyi` with definitions of abstract classes you should stick with following template:

```py
import importlib

class MyLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self._path = path

    def create_module(self, spec : ModuleSpec): -> ModuleType
        '''
            create module by yourself based on specification
        '''
        pass

    def exec_module(mod : ModuleType): -> None
        '''
            execute created module if it's necessary
            you may leave it empty if you didn't do
            anything after creating module.
        '''
        pass

class MyFinder(object):
    def find_spec(sell, fullname : str, path=None): -> ModuleSpec
    '''
        It would run after appending class instance
        into sys.metapath. Should be used to make or find
        your specification.
    '''
    # if you want to create specification from module
    return importlib.util.spec_from_loader(fullname, MyLoader(path))

    sys.meta_path.append(MyFinder())
```